# MongoDB Compass GUI doesn't launch behind proxy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to launch compass on MacOs Ventura 13.4 (22F66). Main factor that I work behind corporate proxy. I see that process of Compass does launch. But GUI doesn't start. I don't see any alerts or notifications.

After I tried to launch app from terminal, I could see error on network level:

```
[23902:0715/175508.208544:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(539)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
[23950:0715/175508.279645:ERROR:validation_errors.cc(117)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED
[23950:0715/175508.280012:ERROR:exception_ports.cc(122)] host_get_exception_ports: (os/kern) invalid argument (4)
[23950:0715/175508.280052:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(695)] Message 1338408258 rejected by interface network.mojom.NetworkService
[23902:0715/175508.281318:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(539)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
```

I guess this is because of proxy.
How can I specify proxy for compass? Where I can find network properties of Compass app?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by setting proxy settings for terminal.